Cubic splines for Cox models
I have a question about cubic splines. I want to be sure that I understood correctly. When I perform a Cox model with proportional hazards, if I insert continous variables in the model I have to check that they have a liner relation with the log(HR). Suppose that I am going to use a Cox model where I have:
Log(HR)= b1X1+b2X2
Where X2 is a categoric variable and X1 is a continous variable. In this case I have to check that X1 is linear respect to log(HR). Therefore, I have:
Log(HR)= b0+b1X1+C
Where C is the cubic component. In this case, I have to test if C=0. If C=0, I can consider X1 respect the linearity and I can use as continous variable in the model. Suppose that C is significant, I do not have linearity between X1 and log(HR). In this case what I have to do? I have to consider the cubic component in the Cox model? Because if I am going to categorize the variable X1, I lose information because I impose that there is the same risk in the same category. Suppose X1=age, I impose that people with age in a specific interval will have same risk of the outcome that I am going to analyze. In case I fail the in the assumption of linearity for a variable, how I have to proceed?
Thank you!
